# Rcpp: Multiply two NumericVectors while subsetting one of them

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have two `NumericVectors` `A` and `B`. The following multiplication works fine when subsetting the vector `B` beforehand:

```
NumericVector B_sub  = B[A - 1];
NumericVector res    = A * B_sub;
```

When I try to do

```
NumericVector res = A * B[A - 1];
```

it yields the error

> invalid operands to binary expression ('NumericVector' (aka 'Vector<14>') and 'SubsetProxy<14, PreserveStorage, 14, true,
>   Rcpp::sugar::Minus_Vector_Primitive<14, true, Rcpp::Vector<14,
>   PreserveStorage> > >')

I suppose this is a common error type in C++. I am an economics student who is involved with R and python but C++ is a new world for me.

**So why is this operation not valid using Rcpp syntactic sugar? Is there a way to make it possible using a type conversion or something similar?**

---

Here is a reproducible **myFun.cpp** file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myFun(NumericVector B) {
  NumericVector A      = wrap(seq_len(B.size()));
  NumericVector B_sub  = B[A - 1];
  NumericVector res    = A * B_sub;
  // NumericVector res = A * B[A - 1];
  return res;
}
```

and the **R-Code** to use `myFun`:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("myFun.cpp")
myFun(1:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as<NumericVector>()`. Create the following "myFun.cpp":

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myFun(NumericVector B) {
    NumericVector A   = wrap(seq_len(B.size()));
    NumericVector res = A * as<NumericVector>(B[A - 1]);
    return res;
}

/*** R
myFun(1:10)
*/
```

Then source and see the results:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("myFun.cpp")

> myFun(1:10)
 [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Comment: Thanks! So the result of `B[A-1]` is not a `NumericVector`. Why would that be? Is'nt it intuitive to assume so?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer That is a great question. I honestly don't understand all of the details behind this (yet -- still learning a lot about C++ and Rcpp myself), but a few weeks ago I ran into a very similar problem and stumbled into this solution. I probably got to it via the excellent [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/), but I can't remember where I picked up this trick or else I would have linked it.

Comment: Yeah I went through the gallery and the other docs found using a big search engine. Must have missed that ;)

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I might have just come up with it by trying random things over and over, so you might not have missed it. I found this related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/392). It looks like sugar objects are not vanilla NumericVectors, and they've solved the issue you had when both inputs to the binary math operators are subsetted vectors (e.g., if the second line of `myFun()` was `NumericVector res = A[A - 1] * as<NumericVector>(B[A - 1])`, this works), but not when only one input is.

Comment: In a handful of characters: "templates". It is complicated, and sometimes we  need to hellp the compiler.